# How to detect Endianess and Filesystem with Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm theorizing of a project where my python script
looks at filesystem(s) on the machine running the script
but also reports back on the filesystem(s) of devices
that it mounts, thumb drives, mobile devices, etc.

Is anyone aware of the a BIF in python3 that would looks at endianness and filesystem.

Finally, I want to make a loop that looks at what storage devices are mounted, but I'm not sure how/whre to access that on OSX or Linux (fstab on linux?) and see what is currently mounted and if that changes. If Fstab was the correct file, would I constantly sort through it or should I just periodically open it and compare it against a file object?
I'm still very new at programming, so please pardon any newbie oversights.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the endianness of the platform:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.byteorder)
little
```

Comment: When I want to start traversing other filesystems and using this module, do you have any suggestions as to how I would go about that?

Comment: I'm confused.  Unless you're going to be examining the raw file system data (unusual for someone "very new at programming") you don't care what the endianness of a filesystem is.

Comment: Might be slightly more helpful if you were to point me in the right direction and say something along the lines of "it's a bit complicated as you have to look at a raw file system, but here are some things to keep in mind or look at."

Comment: If your question was "how do I find out the endianness of the filesystem data for a given filesystem" then I don't know the answer, sorry.  I thought you were interested in the endianness of the processor you were running against.

Answer (score 1):

You can get quite a lot of information about the platform from the `[platform][1]` module. Endianess is from `sys.byteorder` though.

For lists of devices things become more platform-dependent though. There are [various modules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=usb&submit=search) that give you USB access that can give you USB device lists, but nothing to list harddisk for example. Otherwise I don't know of anything platform-independent.